# Wordpress blog display in Firefox browser

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox

The blog or 'thoughts' page of this preliminary wordpress site seems to awkwardly display on top of each other when viewed on firefox.

Can anybody tell me of some general error that I might be making? If it is a more particular error then don't worry about it, I will find out on my own, I was just wondering if there was some general error that I was unaware of.

www.joeldraws.com

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the problem when opening with firefox. which version of firefox you have and in what operating system ?

Comment: It was a very old version of Firefox. It works fine in more recent versions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your markup has some errors with the way you are using `dl`, `dd` and `dt` tags for the gallery. Fix those and see if Firefox displays better. Older versions of Firefox will be more problematic than newer versions.

See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  joeldraws.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//joeldraws.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. Start fixing the code errors and revalidate.